Regular expression to match image tag with empty source attribute?
I have bunch of files like these
<IMG height=694 
src="" width=201>

and I would like to remove all of image tags with empty source attribute.
Which regex I should use to match such tags? They might have different height and width and line breaks in random places.

Which regex engine or flavor (programming language) do you use? Maybe there is even a HTML-parser that can be used to remove the empty tags. Please [edit] and tag your question accordingly.

This question is similar to: RegEx : remove <img which src attribute is empty. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don't use any regex engine and no programming language, the task is data load where we have the data with html in the zip folder and we need to proprocess manually these data before importing to the target environment

I was using regex in sublime editor to edit files manually before the import

The following regexp would solve this
<IMG [a-zA-Z0-9= \n]+src=""[a-zA-Z0-9= \n]+>


And then it is possible to search replace by empty string all occurences in the project
